# An error when use the matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to use the matplotlib in my python program. But I got the follow errors. What's that?

```
      import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      File "C:\Program Files\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line
    24, in <module>
        import matplotlib.colorbar
      File "C:\Program Files\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colorbar.py", lin
    e 29, in <module>
        import matplotlib.collections as collections
      File "C:\Program Files\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\collections.py",
    line 23, in <module>
        import matplotlib.backend_bases as backend_bases
      File "C:\Program Files\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backend_bases.py"
    , line 50, in <module>
        import matplotlib.textpath as textpath
      File "C:\Program Files\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\textpath.py", lin
    e 5, in <module>
        import urllib
      File "C:\Program Files\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 26, in <module>
        import socket
      File "C:\Program Files\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 47, in <module>
        import _socket
   ImportError: No module named _socket
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding "C:\ [PythonDir] \DLLs" to the PYTHONPATH environment variable. That should fix the issue

Comment: @Maybe_hu I had this issue before, _socket is a .pyd file if I remember it correct. I added the C:\Program Files\Python27\DLLs folder to the PYTHONPATH environment variable and it solved the issue for me. Maybe this is a different issue. I will check again

Comment: I found that in the folder  C:\Program Files\Python27\DLLs  I cann't find the _socket file

Comment: @Maybe_hu Can you post your PYTHONPATH

Comment: PTYTHON_HOME=C:\Program Files\Python27 and path=%PYTHON_HOME%;%PYTHON_HOME%\DLLs;

Comment: Can you just try adding a new environment variable PYTHONPATH in windows with the value
C:\Program Files\Python27;C:\Program Files\Python27\Lib;C:\Program Files\Python27\DLLs

Comment: I did as you said, it still doesn't work. The error was the same.